# How to send outlook msg files to excel

Tags: vba, outlook

The following code allows me to import .msg files into excel.
I was wondering if it is possible to create a macro in outlook that sends messages into an excel file rather than importing them.

The code I used for importing .msg files is as follows:

```
Sub IMPORTMSG()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim i As Long
    Dim inPath As String
    Dim thisFile As String
'    Dim Msg As MailItem
    Dim ws As Worksheet
'    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
'    Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem

    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A")

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show = False Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        On Error Resume Next
        inPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
    thisFile = Dir(inPath & "*.msg")
    i = 4
    Do While thisFile <> ""
            Set MyItem = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(inPath & thisFile)
        If MyItem.Subject = "testheader" Then
            ws.Cells(i, 1) = MyItem.Body
            i = i + 1
        End If
            thisFile = Dir()
    Loop

    Set MyItem = Nothing
    Set myOlApp = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "Send" in what sense? How and why are the MSG files created?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko | Users from different departmens send mail in a certain format about issues. Now I save these mail to a folder and import them into excel. I was wondering if it is possible to hit a button in outlook that will send/export this message to a excel file called "reportsA"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a COM addin for Outlook and have it run the code above. Or you can use `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` collection in Outlook to loop through the selected messages in Outlook instead of processing standalone MSG files.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop an Outlook VBA macro where you can automate Excel and set Excel cell values. See [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/219151) for more information.

Also you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.